# rsync error unable to use options

Tags: networking, rsync, transfer

I'm learning rsync.
The man makes my eyes and brain bleed, especially the Option which isn't in alphabetical order and -e has numerous meanings.

I'm testing transferring a file from machine0 to machine1.
I add in options, but then rsync says I'm wrong by not tabbing to complete the file name linuxM (my file to transfer)
Can I rsync with the option -avzhe, if yes, how?

```
rsync -avzhe linuxMint.iso root@192.168.1.140:/DEST
```

Comment: The `-e` option expects to be followed by the name of a transport command to execute in place of the default ssh - why are you trying to use it in this context?

Comment: It's an old command someone helped me with decades ago.  Maybe I can change the option to -aehvz alphabetically?

Comment: No, that won't help. Are you actually trying to use a custom transport command? if not, simply omit the `-e` option

Comment: Umm, yes? a for archive, e for delete file once transferred (I thought), h for human-readable output, v for verbose and z for compress. I've removed the e for now until I figure out how to delete the file from the orgin location.

Comment: Fixed. I need to add ssh after -e.